# Await in catch block

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0, c#-6.0

I have the following code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string result;
try
{
  result = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync( new Uri( "http://badurl" ) );
}
catch
{
  result = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync( new Uri( "http://fallbackurl" ) );
}
```

Basically I want to download from a URL and when it fails with an exception I want to download from another URL. Both time async of course. However the code does not compile, because of

> error CS1985: Cannot await in the body of a catch clause

OK, it's forbidden for whatever reason but what's the correct code pattern here?

**EDIT:**

The good news is that [C# 6.0 will likely allow await calls both in catch and finally blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/magazine/dn683793(en-us).aspx).

Answer (score 108):

**Update:** [C# 6.0 supports await in catch](http://dailydotnettips.com/2014/12/06/using-await-in-a-catch-or-finally-block-in-c-6-0/)

---

**Old Answer**: You can rewrite that code to move the `await` from the `catch` block using a flag:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string result = null;
bool downloadSucceeded;
try
{
  result = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync( new Uri( "http://badurl" ) );
  downloadSucceeded = true;
}
catch
{
  downloadSucceeded = false;
}

if (!downloadSucceeded)
  result = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync( new Uri( "http://fallbackurl" ) );
```

Comment: Thanks svick, that's quite obvious, anything better, more connected to async?

Comment: I don't think anything like that exists.

Comment: In your case, you could also use task continuations. But the code in `svick`'s answer is cleaner than code using continuations.

Comment: If you even need to rethrow the exception without loosing the callstack, you can also use the  `System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo` static class. Simply call `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex)` in your catch block and store the return value, the captured exception, in a local variable. Once you're done with your async code, you can use `capturedException.Throw()` which will properly rethrow the original exception.

Comment: And what VS version is that in? Answer: C# 6 is in the box in Visual Studio 2015 (and its preview).

Answer (score 23):

Awaiting in a catch block is now possible as of the End User Preview of Roslyn [as shown here (Listed under Await in catch/finally)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14) and will be included in C# 6.

The example listed is

```
try … catch { await … } finally { await … }
```

**Update:** Added newer link, and that it will be in C# 6

Answer (score 9):

This seems to work.

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string result;
        Task<string> downloadTask = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://badurl"));
        downloadTask = downloadTask.ContinueWith(
            t => {
                return wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("http://google.com/")).Result;
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        result = await downloadTask;
```

Answer (score 8):

Give this a try:

```
         try
        {
            await AsyncFunction(...);
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        { 
            Utilities.LogExceptionToFile(ex).Wait();
            //instead of "await Utilities.LogExceptionToFile(ex);"
        }
```

(See the `Wait()` ending)

Answer (score 4):

Use C# 6.0. see  this [Link](http://dailydotnettips.com/2014/12/06/using-await-in-a-catch-or-finally-block-in-c-6-0/)

```
public async Task SubmitDataToServer()
{
  try
  {
    // Submit Data
  }
  catch
  {
    await LogExceptionAsync();
  }
  finally
  {
    await CloseConnectionAsync();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `await` after the catch block followed by a `label`, and put a `goto` in the try block.
(No, really! Goto's aren't that bad!)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I use to rethrow the exception after await on a fallback task:

```
ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException = null;
try
{
  await SomeWork();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  capturedException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e);
}

if (capturedException != null)
{
  await FallbackWork();
  capturedException.Throw();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda expression as follows:

```
  try
    {
        //.....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Action<Exception> lambda;

        lambda = async (x) =>
        {
            // await (...);
        };

        lambda(ex);
    }
```

Comment: This makes the lambda `async void`, which should not be used, unless you have to.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar instance, I was unable to await in a catch block. However, I was able to set a flag, and use the flag in an if statement (Code below)

---------------------------------------...

```
boolean exceptionFlag = false; 

try 
{ 
do your thing 
} 
catch 
{ 
exceptionFlag = true; 
} 

if(exceptionFlag == true){ 
do what you wanted to do in the catch block 
}
```