# How to get the JSON error message from HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have a situation where in I have to extract a Response(`HttpResponseMessage`) in a `catch` statement but that I suppose can't be done (using `await` in catch).
Also if i do it after catch , the `HttpResponseMessage` message gets "Disposed".
Code:

```
 private async void MakeHttpClientPostRequest()
 {
     HttpResponseMessage response = null;
     try
     {
         HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
         httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
         HttpContent httpContent = null;
         if (postJSON != null)
         {
             httpContent = new StringContent(postJSON);
             httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
         }

         response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent);
         if (response != null)
         {
             response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
             netResults = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         }

         if (this.convertedType != null)
         {
             MemoryStream assetReader = GetMemoryStreamFromString(netResults);
             assetReader.Position = 0;
             object value = fromJSON(assetReader, this.convertedType);
             networkReqSuccessWithObjectCallback(this, value);
         }
         else
         {
             //Return netResult as string.
             networkReqSuccessWithStringCallback(this, netResults);
         }
     }

     catch (TaskCanceledException)
     {
         ErrorException ee = null;
         ee = new ErrorException("RequestTimeOut");
         NotifyNetworkDelegates(ee);
     }
     catch (HttpRequestException ex)
     {
         //HERE I have to extract the JSON string send by the server
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
     }
}
```

What can be done here ?

---

**Update**
Previous approach using `HttpWebRequest` :

```
public void MakePostWebRequest()
{
    //WebCalls using HttpWebrequest.
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    requestState = RequestState.ERequestStarted;
    asyncResult = request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStream), request);
}


private void GetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
    {
        try
        {
            Stream requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);
            if (request != null)
            {
                using (requestStream)
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
                    writer.Write(postJSON);
                    writer.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
        }
    }
}

private void GetResponseStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    requestState = RequestState.EResponseStream;

    HttpWebRequest request = asyncResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse response;
    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            netResults = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        requestState = RequestState.ERequestCompleted;
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        // failure
        ErrorException ee = null;
        response = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response != null)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                //HERE I'm getting the json error message
                netResults = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        networkReqFailedCallback(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try using the finally block (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: cant be done inside a finally also.

Comment: Why have you got the c#-4.0 tag if you're using `await`?

Comment: If the `catch` block fires, `response` won't have been set by the `try` block, so presumably you're actually trying to access the previous response. It would help if you'd post the full method.

Comment: @Inder: It's not C# 4.5 either - it's C# 5...

Comment: @JonSkeet The server returns some JSON string with error code 500 which needs to be extracted(JSON).

Comment: @Suny: Sure, but you can't use `response` if it hasn't been assigned a value...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes that seem correct but how would I extract the error JSON which I was able to extract using `HttpWebRequest ` the previous approach.

Comment: Well I've asked before to see your full method, and you still haven't shown it. It's not clear how what you've got even compiles, unless you've got some previous response. What exact exception is being thrown? (What's the actual type of `ex` in your `catch` block?)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated my question. And please look at the `//HERE` comment in the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem is that the exception is *actually* thrown by your call to `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`, whose [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode.aspx) contains:

> If the Content is not null, this method will also call Dispose to free managed and unmanaged resources.

Basically it sounds like you shouldn't be using that method to determine the success or failure if you need the content on failure.

Just check the status code yourself, and use the content appropriately based on that code. Note that in your catch block `response` could very easily be null, if the request failed completely.

Comment: I was about to post the same answer.

Comment: A possible solution could be use HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode() which return a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing this is within the try block itself

```
try
{
    response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent);

    netResults = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     //do something with the result
}
catch(HttpRequestException ex)
{
     // catch any exception here
}
```

Catch blocks are used to handle exceptional conditions. Rethrow if required, but should be avoided.

Comment: I am still unclear about your intent here. From your update, I think you want to read the exception information, use the ex instance and properties like Message, StackTrace etc.

Comment: For reading Json responses in c# use Json.Net library (http://json.codeplex.com/) specifically the DeserializeObject<T>(netResults) where netResults is the variable in your code used to hold the response

Answer (score 0):

Response should be available only in case when a remote server actually responded. If Response is `null` (as I understood this is your case), it means that because of some reasons the request wasn't delivered or response wasn't received (doesn't metter which response - with code 200 (OK) or any other code (ERROR)). Please check the error code (`we.Status`). Ensure it is equal `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError` (i.e., the server responded with error); otherwise, some some other error occurred and Response should not be available.