# Message dialog not showing in catch clause

Tags: c#, windows-8, try-catch, async-await

I am using the following code in my Windows 8 app function to catch an error and display an Message Dialog

```
 catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageDialog err = new MessageDialog("Error");
                await err.ShowAsync();


            }
```

But I get an error "cannot await in the body of a catch clause".

But when I remove the `await`, it works but I get a warning on the code "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the await operator to the result of the call".

I need to display a message in this catch clause, how do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868123/await-in-catch-block this link could be of help.

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.  The biggest reason you shouldn't do this is that there is a risk that both your questions will get closed as duplicates of each other.

Comment: Also, FYI - Please read the part 'Where can't I use "await"? from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx#14

Comment: Sorry was getting some internet problems, didn't see it posted successfully, which is why I posted another.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing the work in the `catch`, just set the exception to a local variable.  If it's non-null, then you know you need to handle it after the end of the `catch` block.

```
public static async Task Foo()
{
    Exception e = null;
    try
    {
        //just something to throw an exception
        int a = 0;
        int n = 1 / a;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        e = ex;
    }
    if (e != null)
        await ShowDialog();
}
```